# php Using an or variable in a pdo query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I couldn't find anything similar on this question anywhere so i thought I would ask, is it possible to use a variable that contains the `||` php operator.

For example;

```
if ($regionID == 9) {
    $location = 'Car' || 'Bus' || 'Plane' || 'Train' || 'Bike' || 'Van';
} else {
    echo 'something went wrong';
}

    $sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM transport WHERE location = :location AND status = 2 ORDER BY ref LIMIT :limit OFFSET :start");
    $sql->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

That query throws;

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string
```

I didn't know if it was because of the OR operator in the location variable, and if thats possible to use in this way.

Comment: Well, you should use `WHERE IN ('Car', 'Bus', ...)` instead. That's how its usually done.

Comment: `||` is boolean or in PDO.  It doesn't make sense to apply it to string variables.  So, I guess the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: I can't use WHERE IN, because as shown in the IF statement, if regionID was equal to 8 then the $location string would return a number of other results so where in doesn't make sense in this case.

The only way 'WHERE IN' could work would be to include a different query in every if statement repeating the query everytime

Comment: In order to help you a bit better, we might need to see some other sample data that `$location` might contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$locations` needs to be an array, the way you have it now is a boolean:

```
$locations= array('Car', 'Bus', 'Plane', 'Train', 'Bike', 'Van');
```

Then adjust your code to:

```
$sql ='
SELECT * 
FROM   transport 
WHERE  location IN (:location) 
       AND status = 2 
ORDER  BY ref 
LIMIT  :limit offset :start 
';
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sql->bindValue(':location', implode(",", $locations), PDO::PARAM_STR);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be putting

```
'Car' OR 'Bus' OR 'Plane' OR 'Train' OR 'Bike' OR 'Van'
```

in your query. The better way to do this, based on your design, is:

```
if($region == 9)
    $vehicles = array('Car', 'Bus', 'Plane', 'Train', 'Bike', 'Van');
else { echo 'Something went wrong'; }

    $sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM transport WHERE location IN :location AND status = 2 ORDER BY ref LIMIT :limit OFFSET :start");
    $sql->bindValue(':location', implode(",", $vehicles));
```

I haven't tested it, but I THINK that can work. Otherwise, you could put it straight into the query via string concatenation as this doesn't look like data that can be tampered with.